# Long boot time on debian : "usb 1-x: new high-speed USB device number y using xhci_hcd"

Tags: debian, boot

Hello when I boot my keyboard takes 2 to 3 minutes to get activated so it slows my boot tremendously as I need to enter a passphrase to unlock a partition. I booted using the kernel parameter `ignore_loglevel` it looks like the system is cycling through all the usb ports and the keyboard gets activated only when it reach the good one. The cycling takes a long time, for every port it says :

```
usb 1-3: new high speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
device descriptor read/8, error -110
```

It takes 10-20sec per port and my keyboard get activated only when it reaches the port on which my keyboard is plugged in. Any idea on how to fix this issue ?

**Update:**
This is a list of critical lines in `dmesg`:

```
[    2.545550 <    0.515279>] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[   11.442200 <    8.896650>] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[   11.609957 <    0.167757>] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[   21.725142 <   10.115185>] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/all, error -110
[   21.892918 <    0.167776>] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[   26.902612 <    5.009694>] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   32.016120 <    5.113508>] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   32.231808 <    0.215688>] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   37.241509 <    5.009701>] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[   42.355008 <    5.113499>] usb 1-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
...
[   44.168565 <    0.009941>] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  299.444985 <  255.276420>] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
[ 2306.154859 < 2006.709874>] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[ 2398.435936 <   92.281077>] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[ 2422.401403 <   23.965467>] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Comment: May you add the result `dmesg -d` right after your boot. you may paste it here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha sure there you go : paste.ubuntu.com/15485978

Comment: have you tried changing the load order of the usb hci modules?  e.g. so that `uhci_hcd` or `ehci_hcd` loads before `xhci_hcd`?   on debian, you'd do that by editing `/etc/modules`, adding the modules in the order you want them loaded, and then rebuilding your initramfs with `update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)` or `update-initramfs -u -k all`, and then rebooting.

Comment: @cas yes I already followed [these instrutions](http://www.kasploosh.com/weblog/14000/14016-debian_jessie_usb_keyboard.html) to no effect. I tried to add  `xhci_hcd` at the end of the modules file to no effect either.

Comment: What kernel version are you running?  have you tried running a newer kernel, either from testing or sid (which both have 4.4 kernels available), or from https://liquorix.net/ ?  i had USB problems with error messages similar to yours (but for my quad DVB-T usb-on-pcie card, not my keyboard) with kernels above 3.19 until late in the 4.3 series (4.3-3.dmz.6 as released by liquorix).   if you upgrade the kernel and if you use any dkms modules, don't forget to install the linux-headers-* package as well as the linux-image-* package.

Comment: @cas I have debian testing with kernel 4.3, at least it's booting that's an improvement compared to jessie that wouldn't boot at all (unable to make a vram boot entry). I'll try to get 4.4 and keep you updated thanks

Comment: @cas damn just installed kernel 4.4.0.1 and still the same problem

Comment: the only other thing i can think of is to try plugging the keyboard into another port...run `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` whilst plugging the kbd into different ports until you find the lowest numbered port, then leave it there.  btw, what kind of computer is it? brand/model, motherboard if self-built? what kind of USB port chipset(s)?

Answer (score 1):

fix from upstream https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/patch/include/linux/usb.h?id=feb26ac31a2a5cb88d86680d9a94916a6343e9e6

ubuntu bug report : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1437492